# Cross- thread operation not valid

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, exception

This line throws the exception (I'm talking about a windows form. the PointToClient is a method of the form):

```
double x = PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X / this.Width;
```

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread
>   other than the thread it was created on.

What control is being accessed? I know I should use invoke, but what control should I invoke? I'm really puzzled.

Comment: Just write the error message to google. First Result.......

Comment: @L.B The poster already mentioned that - "I know I should use invoke" - its actually NOT a duplicate of the other...  The problem here was the OP didn't realize the form itself is a control, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What control is being accessed?

`this` is the `Form`, which derives from `Control`.  You can use `this.Invoke` to marshal it back to the UI thread.